# db date time with timezone in a specific format

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get db date and time using a sql query in the format like
"2016-01-26T12:07:41-08:00"

the select systimestamp from dual gives me value like
2016-02-03 10:39:29.099545 -8:00

so what should be the right query for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
select to_char(systimestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM') time_stamp
from   dual;

TIME_STAMP                                         
---------------------------------------------------
2016-02-04T12:20:33-05:00
```

Comment: Note `TZR` means "Time zone **region name**". This can be a string like `-08:00`, however it can be also `US/Pacific`. Use `TZH:TZM` to get always the hour:minute offset to UTC.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit ah, thanks! I'll update my answer to include that; I was a bit hasty when I tested it!

Answer (score -1):

I am not 100% on what your desired format is as you seem to give the same format twice.
However, if you want to change the format of systimestamp output you could do something like this:
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'dd/mm/yy') FROM DUAL;

Result:
04/02/16

Comment: sorry fixed the question

Comment: Format `dd/mm/yy` is certainly different to what is requested: `2016-01-26T12:07:41-08:00`

Comment: Yes it is - so that it would be clear that it was only and example and that the point of  the reply was to illustrate how to reformat the date generally